# The appointments were contained inside a decree signed on January

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Which one is preferable?

> The appointments were contained **in** a decree signed on January

or

> The appointments were contained **inside** a decree signed on January

Do I say **in** a decree or **inside** a decree?

Answer (score 1):

Neither is idiomatic.

You either need to say:

> ....in January...
>   or
>   ....on January 5 (or any other date to follow January)

However, to say **in a decree** indicates that you are talking about the text of the decree. The decree included text concerning the appointments.

To say **inside a decree** sounds as though the appointments were found on paper rolled up inside the material on which the decree was written, as if one document had been found inside another.

So, presuming that you have the first sense in mind, prefer **...in a decree....**